# Creating Pay and Configure Products on Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce, rules

I am using Commerce Product Option (https://drupal.org/project/commerce_option) module to create a customisable product.

I want a way in which the user can checkout and make payment for the product and then be allowed to customise it. What would be the ideal set of Rules for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This module set only supports customizing the product prior to checkout. Achieving customization after checkout will require custom module development.